# Surface through integral

Tags: calculus

We are asked to find the area of ​​the passage defined by $y = x^2-8x + 12$ and its tangent lines at points $(0, 12)$ and $(6, 0)$.

I found the points of intersection of the curve with each tangent line
($y_1 = -8x + 12$ and $y_2 = 4x-24$), as well as the point of intersection of the lines and so I came to:
$E = E_1 + E_2$,
where $E_1$ is the integral of the difference $(y - y_1)$ where $x$ is from $0$ to $3$ and $E_2$ is the integral of the difference $(y - y_2)$ where $x$ is from $3$ to $6$.

However, I came to the conclusion that $E = 0$, having controlled my actions very well.
I would appreciate for your guidance.

Comment: Probably a miscalculation. I calculated it and found $18$. Could you show your working which led to $E=0$?

Comment: Thank you very much! So it is 9+9 = 18, right? 
According to my post, I reached the conclusion that 
E =  27/3 + (36-12*6+36)-(9-12*3+36) = 9 + 0 - 9 = 0

Comment: Yup, the answer by Math Lover is correct

Answer (score 1):

At the intersection of both tangents,

$y = - 8x+12 = 4x-24 \implies x = 3, y = - 12$

Note that both tangents meet below the parabola. So the integral to find area of the bound region is,

$ =\displaystyle \int_0^3 ((x^2 - 8x + 12) - (-8x+12)) ~ dx ~ + $ $ \displaystyle  \int_3^6 ((x^2 - 8x + 12) - (4x-24)) ~ dx$

$ = \displaystyle \int_0^3 x^2 ~ dx + \int_3^6 (6-x)^2  ~ dx = 9 + 9 = 18$

Comment: Thank you very much!!!